# Is it possible to use Azure policy to restrict the creation or upload of any JSON file in a storage account?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-policy

I'm trying to create an Azure policy in which I should restrict everyone from uploading or creating JSON files. My logic is that any file name ending in.JSON will be denied.
but how to get blob name?

Comment: {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs.name",
          "endsWith": ".json"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  }

Comment: field Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs.name is not available in Azure Policy.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible** because the properties `name` or `contentType` are not available.
[image]

Use this command to see all available aliases that you can use in a policy:

```
Get-AzPolicyAlias -NamespaceMatch Microsoft.Storage | where ResourceType -like 'storageAccounts*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ‘Aliases’ | Select name
```

Please open a CSS ticket at https://azure.microsoft.com/support/create-ticket to request new aliases.